# NSString to NSDate give wrong date

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsdate

I have `NSString` of date :

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Feb-02-17";
```

I try to convert it to date with :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM-dd-yy"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

And in `yourDate` i get this value:

```
2017-02-01 22:00:00 +0000
```

Any idea why there is a difference between the dates?

Comment: Its probably `timezone` issue.

Comment: Yep, just add timezone with `UTC` abbreviation to the date formatter, it's just converting UTC time to your current timezone time.

Comment: The date is correct. `NSDateFormatter` creates the date considering your local time zone (UTC +2) but `print` prints dates in UTC. `2017-02-01 22:00:00 +0000` and `2017-02-02 00:00:00 +0200` is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the current locale to make your current timezone is used for transforming the date into string.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM-dd-yy"];
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Otherwise it will be in UTC.